# Display coordinates as surf in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I know this might be a stupid question but I feel like I don't quite understand how MATLAB works. I have a set of points (3d) that I want to display as a surf or mesh. 
I've put them into the following matrix:

```
A = [0, 0, 12.2
0.5, 0.5, 14
0, 1, 14.4
1, 0, 12.6
1, 1, 14.6];
```

the first column is x, second is y and the last is supposed to be z.
Now my problem is that MATLAB wants z to be a matrix, which is not the case for me. But there must be a way to display what I have in mind right?

Comment: `surf(A(1,:),A(2,:),A(3:end,:))` ?

Comment: I don't get an error anymore when using your code @pkpkpk but the result is not what it should be somehow.

Comment: With first row and x, second row as y and third, fourth and fifth rows as z that's the output of the surf function. Are you sure surf function is what you are after, and that those points are correct?

Comment: yes, you are right, it does work this way! The axes just don't end at 1, which is why I was confused. Thank you @pkpkpk :)

Comment: `surf` works on a grid. All inputs `X`, `Y` and `Z` must be 2D matrices. What you have is only a set of 3D points. You can use `plot3` to display them in 3D. If you want a _surface_ out of that set, you will have to interpolate your 'Z' data over an `X,Y` grid.